# Multithreaded merge sort when used on large data sets misses sorting some elements?

Tags: c, multithreading, floating-point, mergesort, bigdata

**HOMEWORK EXERCISE**

I am partitioning my data into smaller matrices and using threads to optimise the recursive sorts. My function works perfectly on small data sets where the no of elements doesn't exceed about 2000. However once the data starts getting bigger than that I start to get some elements out of order and don't get any memory errors when running address sanitiser or valgrind. I haven't been able to figure it out. I did try to change the pivot to have an if statement with a modulo for even or odd amounts of elements to partition by `n/2` for even and `(n+1)/2` for odd but that still didn't work. Can anyone see what I've missed or just give me a hint?

```
// struct used for merge sort threads
typedef struct {
    float* m;
    size_t n;
} thread_arg;

/*
 * Merge matrices together
 */
void merge(float* main_matrix, float* left_matrix, int left_elements, float* right_matrix, int right_elements) {
    // left_matrix index
    int l = 0;
    // right_matrix index
    int r = 0;
    // main_matrix index
    int m = 0;

    while (l < left_elements && r < right_elements) {
        if (left_matrix[l] < right_matrix[r]) {
            main_matrix[m++] = left_matrix[l++];
        } else {
            main_matrix[m++] = right_matrix[r++];
        }
    }

    while (l < left_elements) {
        main_matrix[m++] = left_matrix[l++];
    }

    while (r < right_elements) {
        main_matrix[m++] = right_matrix[r++];
    }
}

/*
 * Threaded merge sort
 */
void* merge_sort(void* arg) {
    thread_arg* t_arg = (thread_arg*) arg;

    // base case
    if (t_arg->n < 2) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t pivot = (t_arg->n / 2);

    // left and right sub-matrices
    float* left_matrix = malloc(sizeof(float) * pivot);
    float* right_matrix = malloc(sizeof(float) * (t_arg->n - pivot));

    // fill left_matrix
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pivot; i++) {
        left_matrix[i] = t_arg->m[i];
    }

    // fill right_matrix
    for (size_t i = pivot; i < t_arg->n; i++) {
        right_matrix[(i - pivot)] = t_arg->m[i];
    }

    // create structs for recursive thread call
    thread_arg t_arg1 = (thread_arg) {
        .m = left_matrix,
        .n = pivot
    };
    thread_arg t_arg2 = (thread_arg) {
        .m = right_matrix,
        .n = (t_arg->n - pivot)
    };

    // create threads and send structs to sort recursively
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, merge_sort, &t_arg1);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, merge_sort, &t_arg2);
    // join threads to retrieve sorted sub-matrices
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    // Merge left_matrix and right_matrix into sorted matrix.
    merge(t_arg->m, left_matrix, pivot, right_matrix, (t_arg->n - pivot));

    // free left and right matrices
    free(left_matrix);
    free(right_matrix);

    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Returns sorted matrix.
 */
float* sort(float* matrix) {
    float* result = cloned(matrix);

    // structs for threaded merge sort
    thread_arg t_arg = (thread_arg) {
        .m = result,
        .n = g_elements
    };

    merge_sort(&t_arg);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: could not find the problem yet but as a sidenote: it is confusing that you call them matrix instead of array.

Comment: @BerndElkemann they are matrices in row major order. m[((row * height) + col)]

Comment: Is this the problem?: `if (l_matrix[l] < r_matrix[r])` The function's arguments are `left_matrix` and  `right_matrix`. (Is `l_matrix` a global which explains that you dont get a comple-error?)

Comment: Fyi, don't launch two threads per recursion. It makes little sense to launch two threads, then have the parent thread just sit there and wait for both. Rather, launch *one* thread, then have the parent thread *perform* what the second *would* do (just invoke the recursion), then wait for the launched thread, then do the merge. Also, don't recurse more than the core-count of your machine. If you think that doesn't matter, consider the number of partitions at the deepest level (part-len = 2) in a matrix of, say just 2048 elements. Yeah, thats 1024 active threads. not gonna work. limit that.

Comment: ...and to answer your question about where things can go wrong. You never check the results of `pthread_create`, so see the last subject of my prior comment on limiting depth of threading.

Comment: @BerndElkemann no I had just changed the names to be more descriptive for stack overflow

Comment: @WhozCraig `pthread_create` failing (and OP not checking) is indeed the problem here (the associated small sub-matrix stays unsorted). You should post this as an answer. @OP: and also check malloc return value.

Comment: I added `if (pthread_create(thread1, NULL, merge_sort, t_arg1) != 0) { perror("Failed to create pthread\n"); }` and it did fail multiple times. Going to try and fix it now.

Comment: Also, allocating storage the way you do is a waste. Consider the top-level caller allocating two arrays of the same size, and passing both to the recursion, one as the source array and the other as a work area. Intermediate callers will not allocate anything and pass ranges of these arrays to the recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared to be not checking if the pthread_create is failing. By amending the code to have a check you can then do a unthreaded call in the case of all threads being used. Here is some pseudo code.

```
// create threads and send structs to recursively sort
pthread_t thread1;
if (pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, merge_sort, &t_arg1) != 0 || t_arg->n_threads == MAX_THREADS) {
    merge_sort(&t_arg1);
} else {
    no. of threads++
}

merge_sort(&t_arg2);

pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
no. of threads--
```

Comment: Note: the order of that two-piece expression should be reversed; you should only try to start a new thread if you haven't hit your ceiling already. And you should protect against invoking pthread_join against a failed thread-start handle. Regardless, the idea is correct.

Answer (score -3):

I think you have a race condition as I do not see any locks. You must protect your shared data against simultaneous access from several threads.

Comment: The threads work on separate arrays and the parent-thread waits on each of the two sub-threads to finish